# Check Objective-C generics type in for loop (fast enumeration)

Tags: objective-c, typechecking, fast-enumeration

Is there any compiler option to warn that the type in the for-in loop is wrong?

```c
    NSArray<NSString *> *stringsArray = @[ @"Hello", @"World" ];
    for (UIView *wrongType in stringsArray) {
        NSLog(@"object: %@", wrongType);
    }
```

Comment: No. There's nothing you can do.

Comment: Oh... I see now what you mean, my mistake. Sorry...

Comment: You can use `typeof(stringsArray.firstObject)` instead of explicit type in `for-in` statement

Comment: Can you confirm... do you want the compiler to check that the type specified in code in the loop is the same as the type in the array? Or are you checking that the array doesn’t contain any UIView (for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Since NSArray may contain objects of multiple classes, there are no way for compiler to detect wrong class in such for loop.

Source - iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide

Comment: Why couldn't the compiler check? My NSArray is parameterized to `NSString*`. (I know the runtime can't check, because the types are erased.)

Comment: I suppose I have no deep enough knowledge to answer why.
In your case, if you will add some UIView object to your stringsArray - it will be processed in for loop. Other types will not.